# Live Paint Bucket Tool does not recognize all sections of image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I created a rectangle and added two lines inside (it is meant to be a table that will hold text).  I want to target selected sections within the overall rectangle, but the Live Paint Bucket Tool only sees the larger rectangle, as below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how can I have the internal lines of the rectangle turn red?

**EDIT:**

Based on [joojaa](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa)'s comment, I closely checked the figure, and each point is similar to what's shown below, and has a point of intersection:

[image]

Comment: There might be a small gap

Comment: @joojaa Thanks, based on your input, I checked the file, and have updated my question.

Comment: How do you know its not the intersection of the continuation line?

Comment: @joojaa I don't.  I am pretty new to Ai, and really don't know how many types of intersection there are.

Comment: hit conrl y and zoom close. Also add the gap detection in tool oprions

Comment: Did you grouped the objects first? In previous version of Illustrator we need to group the objects. Today we no longer need to group them.

Comment: @joojaa If you could explain, based on my answer below, why this problem happened, I will be happy to accept your answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by clicking "Merge Live Paint" button on the control panel, as described by the following message:

[image]

Result:

[image]

I am happy that the problem went away, but I don't understand why the paths were in an unmerged state in the first place.  In any case, I hope this information will help someone else in the future.